# Unable to retrieve cookies set by Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

According to the official docs on cookies:

> By default, all cookies generated by Laravel are encrypted and signed so that they can't be modified or read by the client. If you would like to disable encryption for a subset of cookies generated by your application, you may use the $except property of the App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies middleware, which is located in the app/Http/Middleware directory

In my controller that sends a response with cookies, I set a cookie with `return response("Success", 200)->cookie('api_token', $api_token, 2, '/');`, where `$api_token` is a string generated by `Str::random(80)`. I have a route in `web.php` that is protected by middleware that checks if the cookie is valid. However, using `$request->cookie('api_token');` in the middleware returns nothing, but I have to make an exception in the `EncryptCookies` for `api_token` to make this work.

I'm not sure why my cookie isn't being encrypted, even if I use a laravel function to set it. Am I misunderstanding which cookies are "generated" by Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Set Cookies :

```
public function setCookie(Request $request){
  $minutes = 60;
  $response = new Response('Set Cookie');
  $response->withCookie(cookie('name', 'MyValue', $minutes));
  return $response;
}
```

Get Cookies :

```
public function getCookie(Request $request){
  $value = $request->cookie('name');
  echo $value;
}
```